# Tensorflow gather indexes and expand

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `[batch, num_objs, vals]` or `(16, 4, 10)` tensor `y` in which `y[:,:,:2]` has the (row, col) indexes into a `[batch, rows, cols, num_objs, vals]` or `[16, 40, 60, 2, 10]` tensor `y'`.  Now each `y[i,:,:2]` may have the exact same (row, col) indexes or they may all be unique.  I want to  map all the 10 dimensional vals of `y` onto `y'` based on the (row, col) indexes from `y[:,:,:2]`.  I will be reducing the `num_objs` dimension from 4 to 2 and throwing away 1 or 2 vectors if more than 2 map to the same grid cell.

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056074/3614578 I have an index tensor based on `y[:,:,:2]`.  Here is what I have

```
true_grid_coords = y[:,:,:2] // params.grid_stride
true_grid_vals = tf.concat([true_grid_coords, y[:,:,2:]], axis=2)
s1 = tf.shape(true_grid_coords, out_type=true_grid_coords.dtype)
b = tf.range(s1[0])
# Repeat batch index for each object
b = tf.repeat(b, s1[1]) # (64) 16 times num_obj
# Concatenate with row and column indices - (64, 1) concat (64, 2) = (64, 3), b is first col, true coords second, third col
# vals in first col(each batch index 0-15) repeated 4 times from repeat function
idx = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(b, 1), tf.reshape(true_grid_coords, [-1, s1[2]])], axis=1)
s2 = tf.shape(y\')
# I want to index into first 3 dims of s2 and expand by adding (4, 10) tensor from indexing into y[:,:,:2]
true_grid_vals = tf.scatter_nd(idx, y, s2[:3])
```

I need to use `idx` to index into the rows and cols in `[batch, rows, cols, num_objs, vals]` and the rows, cols in `y[:,:,:2]` while extracting the entire length 10 vector(s) from `y`.  The number of vectors can be `match` and will be between 0 and 4.  `Match` can truncated or expanded to 2 (`num_objs`) and if there are no matches or 1 match the other vector(s) can be all zeroes. Then append that `(num_objs, 10)` tensor to the `[batch, rows, cols, num_objs, vals]` tensor `y'` at the appropriate (row, col).  How could I do this? Does this make sense?

For example, one sample `i` in the batch `y[i]` would be a [4, 10] shaped tensor

```
[1, 5, ....]
[30, 20, ....]
[37, 51, ....]
[37, 51, ....]
```

These first 2 numbers in each row can be used as indexes into the first and second dimensions of a tensor of shape `[16, 40, 60, 2, 10]` called `y'`.  I want to map each row above into the `[16, 40, 60, 2, 10]` tensor based on the first 2 numbers in the rows above, and the appropriate batch index `i`.  In the example above for batch `i`,  2 vectors would map to `[i, 37, 51,:,:]`, one vector to `[i, 30, 20,0,:]`, and one to `[i, 1, 5,0,:]`.  Every other value in `y'[i,:,:,:,:]` would be 0.  If there had been 3 rows above with coordinates `[37, 51, ...]`, one of them would be discareded.

Comment: To take slices of a tensor using indices, use [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather)

Comment: Could you please provide example. Given some numerical input what output do you expect?

Comment: Added a concrete example

Comment: I just made this a pre processing step and used a for loop